# CppUnitTestFramework: Test Method Fails, Stack Trace Lists Line Number at the End of Method, Debug Test Passes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I know, I know - that question title is very much all over the place. However, I am not sure what could be an issue here that is causing what I am witnessing.

I have the following method in class `Project` that is being unit tested:

```
bool Project::DetermineID(std::string configFile, std::string& ID)
{
    std::ifstream config;
    config.open(configFile);

    if (!config.is_open()) {
        WARNING << "Failed to open the configuration file for processing ID at: " << configFile;
        return false;
    }

    std::string line = "";
    ID = "";

    bool isConfigurationSection = false;
    bool isConfiguration = false;

    std::string tempID = "";

    while (std::getline(config, line))
    {
        std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), ::toupper); // transform the line to all capital letters
        boost::trim(line);

        if ((line.find("IDENTIFICATIONS") != std::string::npos) && (!isConfigurationSection)) {

            // remove the "IDENTIFICATIONS" part from the current line we're working with
            std::size_t idStartPos = line.find("IDENTIFICATIONS");
            line = line.substr(idStartPos + strlen("IDENTIFICATIONS"), line.length() - idStartPos - strlen("IDENTIFICATIONS"));
            boost::trim(line);

            isConfigurationSection = true;
        }

        if ((line.find('{') != std::string::npos) && isConfigurationSection) {

            std::size_t bracketPos = line.find('{');

            // we are working within the ids configuration section
            // determine if this is the first character of the line, or if there is an ID that precedes the { 

            if (bracketPos == 0) {
                // is the first char
                // remove the bracket and keep processing

                line = line.substr(1, line.length() - 1);
                boost::trim(line);
            }
            else {
                // the text before { is a temp ID

                tempID = line.substr(0, bracketPos - 1);
                isConfiguration = true;

                line = line.substr(bracketPos, line.length() - bracketPos);
                boost::trim(line);
            }
        }

        if ((line.find("PORT") != std::string::npos) && isConfiguration) {

            std::size_t indexOfEqualSign = line.find('=');

            if (indexOfEqualSign == std::string::npos) {
                WARNING << "Unable to determine the port # assigned to " << tempID;
            }
            else {
                std::string portString = "";
                portString = line.substr(indexOfEqualSign + 1, line.length() - indexOfEqualSign - 1);
                boost::trim(portString);

                // confirm that the obtained port string is not an empty value

                if (portString.empty()) {
                    WARNING << "Failed to obtain the \"Port\" value that is set to " << tempID;
                }
                else {

                    // attempt to convert the string to int

                    int workingPortNum = 0;

                    try {
                        workingPortNum = std::stoi(portString);
                    }
                    catch (...) {
                        WARNING << "Failed to convert the obtained \"Port\" value that is set to " << tempID;
                    }

                    if (workingPortNum != 0) {
                        // check if this port # is the same port # we are publishing data on

                        if (workingPortNum == this->port) {
                            ID = tempID;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    config.close();

    if (ID.empty())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

The goal of this method is to parse any text file for the ID portion, based on matching the port # that the application is publishing data to.

Format of the file is like this:

```
Idenntifications {
  ID {
    port = 1001
  }
}
```

In a separate Visual Studio project that unit tests various methods, including this `Project::DetermineID` method.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define EXPAND(x) STRINGIFY(x)

TEST_CLASS(ProjectUnitTests) {
    Project* parser;
    std::string projectDirectory;

    TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE(ProjectUnitTestInitialization) {
        projectDirectory = EXPAND(UNITTESTPRJ);
        projectDirectory.erase(0, 1);
        projectDirectory.erase(projectDirectory.size() - 2);

        parser = Project::getClass(); // singleton method getter/initializer
    }

    // Other test methods are present and pass/fail accordingly

    TEST_METHOD(DetermineID) {
        std::string ID = "";

        bool x = parser ->DetermineAdapterID(projectDirectory + "normal.cfg", ID);
        Assert::IsTrue(x);
    }
};
```

Now, when I run the tests, `DetermineID` fails and the stack trace states:

```
   DetermineID
   Source: Project Tests.cpp line 86
   Duration: 2 sec

  Message: 
    Assert failed
  Stack Trace: 
    ProjectUnitTests::DetermineID() line 91
```

Now, in my test .cpp file, `TEST_METHOD(DetermineID) {` is present on line 86. But that method's `}` is located on line 91, as the stack trace indicates.

And, when debugging, the unit test passes, because the return of `x` in the `TEST_METHOD` is `true`.
Only when running the test individually or running all tests does that test method fail.

Some notes that may be relevant:

- This is a single-threaded application with no tasks scheduled (no race condition to worry about supposedly)
- There is another method in the `Project` class that also processes a file with an `std::ifstream` same as this method does

  - That method has its own test method that has been written and passes without any problems
  - The test method also access the "normal.cfg" file
- Yes, `this->port` has an assigned value

Thus, my questions are:

1. Why does the stack trace reference the closing bracket for the test method instead of the single `Assert` within the method that is supposedly failing?
2. How to get the unit test to pass when it is ran? (Since it currently only plasses during debugging where I can confirm that `x` is `true`).
3. If the issue is a race condition where perhaps the other test method is accessing the "normal.cfg" file, why does the test method fail even when the method is individually ran?

Any support/assistance here is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: TL;DR; I'd suspect you have introduced UB somewhere (not necessarily in that parts of code you're showing).

Comment: UB? Sorry, have never heard that term ...

Comment: It means [_undefined behavior_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). In english it's _"Shit hit the fan."_ Your mention that your code behaves differently in debug vs release mode, is a typical symptom. Sometimes static code analysis tools can help in detection of such bugs.